# Applying transform with JavaScript on mousemove doesn't update on the fly

Tags: javascript, css, dom

trying to make a div draggable, but only along the x-axis, the way a timestamp thumb on a video control can be dragged left and right to seek through a video or audio presentation.

Here's my code

```
  thumb.addEventListener('mousemove', updateThumbPosition, false)

  function updateThumbPosition (event) {
    var thumbRect = thumb.getBoundingClientRect()
    var startX = seekbar.getBoundingClientRect().left
    var mouseX = event.clientX
    console.log(mouseX - startX + thumbRect.width / 2)
    thumb.style.transform = 'translateX(' + mouseX - startX + thumbRect.width / 2 + 'px)'
  }
```

The div doesn't move. The values change rapidly as the mouse moves. I can see that when I log to the console, but the div itself does not translate along the X axis. Thoughts?

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/btjLqa8u/1/

Comment: This code, in itself is fine. A Jsfiddle would help finding the real issue.

Comment: Added fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/btjLqa8u/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only missing parentheses:  https://jsfiddle.net/rjzLtunb/

```
 div.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (mouseX - startX) + 'px)'
```

By the way, for drag and drop code, you probably want to listen for mouse moves on the div parent instead of the div itself.

Comment: fml (required more characters to post a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

I updated you fiddle with better mouse handling.

jsfiddle

[s4mj3ch9](https://jsfiddle.net/s4mj3ch9/)

```
var div = document.getElementById('div')

div.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);

function updateDivPosition (event) {
  var divRect = div.getBoundingClientRect()
  var startX = seekbar.getBoundingClientRect().left
  var mouseX = event.clientX
  div.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (mouseX - startX) + 'px)'
}
function mouseUp(){
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', updateDivPosition, true);
}
function mouseDown(){
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateDivPosition, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I updated your update to grab the div in the middle as opposed to its left edge. And got rid of the highlighting that was happening. Now to create some left and right bounds : ) Thanks for the help!